# jQuery: Storing a Div name in a variable, then calling it in an action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i've been trying to wrap my head around this, all i'm trying to do is store a div name in a variable for easy editing, then allow it to be called in standard actions such as show/hide.

Without the variables, my code works fine but with them it will not load the div, i've done a console log to make sure it knows what the div name is based off the stored variable and it returns correctly.

Here is my code:-

```
var buttonActive = 0;
var yourMenuDiv = '.menu-menu-1-container';

$(function() {

    $(yourMenuDiv).before('<div class="responsiveButton"><div id="rBBar"></div><div id="rBBar"></div><div id="rBBar"></div></div>');
    $(yourMenuDiv).before('<div class="responsiveMenu"><div id="responsiveTitle"></div></div>');
    $(yourMenuDiv + 'ul').clone().appendTo('.responsiveMenu');
    $('.home #logoImage').clone().appendTo('#responsiveTitle');

    console.log(yourMenuDiv);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            $(yourMenuDiv).hide();
            $('.responsiveMenu, .responsiveButton').show();
        }else{
            $('.responsiveMenu').removeClass('expandMenu');
            $('.responsiveButton').removeClass('expandMenuButton');
            $('.responsiveMenu, .responsiveButton').hide();
            $(yourMenuDiv).show();
            buttonActive = 0;
        }
    });

    $(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            $(yourMenuDiv).hide();
            $('.responsiveMenu, .responsiveButton').show();
        }else{
            $('.responsiveMenu, .responsiveButton').hide();
            $(yourMenuDiv).show();
            buttonActive = 0;
        }
    });  

    $('.responsiveButton').click(function() {
        if (buttonActive == 0){
            $('.responsiveMenu').addClass('expandMenu');
            $('.responsiveButton').addClass('expandMenuButton');
            buttonActive = 1;
        }else{
            $('.responsiveMenu').removeClass('expandMenu');
            $('.responsiveButton').removeClass('expandMenuButton');
            buttonActive = 0;
        }
    });

});
```

Thank you

Comment: one problem is missing space for `yourMenuDiv + 'ul'` would result in selector `'.menu-menu-1-containerul'`

Comment: Note you have nested DOM ready handlers. You do not need the inside one (although it is harmless to have them, it is a waste of code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
 $(yourMenuDiv + 'ul').clone().appendTo('.responsiveMenu');
```

Does the above line work correctly? - I mean should there be a space character in between. Something like below:

```
$(yourMenuDiv + ' ul').clone().appendTo('.responsiveMenu');
```

and as a matter of interest. Does it make any difference if you place your first two lines of code:

```
var buttonActive = 0;
var yourMenuDiv = '.menu-menu-1-container';
```

after `$(function() {` ?

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right the ul just needed the spacing, i feel a little silly now, just waiting for the time to accept this as an answer, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like:

```
var yourMenuDiv = $('.menu-menu-1-container');
```

and then just call the methods with: **yourMenuDiv.**`methodHere`.

Comment: this will fail if it is placed outside of the ready handler the way OP code declaration is currently

Comment: This did not work turns out the problem comes from the lack of space between the variable and ul, thank you though